# Bootstrap Tab no longer functional in Angular CLI 13.3.0

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng-bootstrap

**Issue Details**

on clicking Change Password tab, there was an error message: **Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'v-ChangePassword'**

Am I missing anything?

[image]

Below is the screenshot of page where tabs are located.

[image]

Bootstrap has been added in the app module: `import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';`

**Html Code**

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
        <a 
            class="nav-link active" 
            id="v-profile-tab" 
            data-toggle="pill" 
            href="#v-profile" 
            role="tab" 
            aria-controls="v-profile" 
            aria-selected="true">
            Profile
        </a>
        <a 
            class="nav-link" 
            id="v-ChangePassword-tab" 
            data-toggle="pill" 
            href="#v-ChangePassword" 
            role="tab" 
            aria-controls="v-ChangePassword" 
            aria-selected="true">
            Change Password
        </a>
        <a 
            class="nav-link" 
            id="v-AccountAccessHistory-tab" 
            data-toggle="pill" 
            href="#v-AccountAccessHistory" 
            role="tab" 
            aria-controls="v-AccountAccessHistory" 
            aria-selected="true">
            Access History
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="tab-content" id="v-tabContent">
        <div 
            class="tab-pane fade show active" 
            id="v-profile" 
            role="tabpanel" 
            aria-labelledby="v-profile-tab">
            <basicsettings></basicsettings>
        </div>
        <div 
            class="tab-pane fade show" 
            id="v-ChangePassword" 
            role="tabpanel" 
            aria-labelledby="v-ChangePassword-tab">
            <changepassword></changepassword>
        </div>
        <div 
            class="tab-pane fade show" 
            id="v-AccountAccessHistory" 
            role="tabpanel" 
            aria-labelledby="v-AccountAccessHistory-tab">
            <accesslogs></accesslogs>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the href attributes on the tab are changing the URL. The Angular router is trying to resolve a route for the URL and failing, which is the error being shown.

To fix it, you can implement vertical tabs like the example [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/nav/examples).

By the way, you should really be tagging this question with `ng-bootstrap` as it's more of an `ng-bootstrap` question than pure Angular.